# Создать анимированный баннер

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, анимация

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите пожалуйста, что можно почитать/погуглить на тему создания анимированного баннера, используя при этом HTML5, CSS3 и JS.

В баннере должны быть реализованы интерактивные функциональные возможности (при наведении/нажатии и т.д.)

Использовать при этом можно ТОЛЬКО HTML5, CSS3 и JS + jQuery. Нельзя использовать GIF'ки и "слайдеры".

Comment: Возможно вам нужен [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Статейка на хабре:**

- http://habrahabr.ru/post/169387/

**У гугла есть своя разработка для этого:**

- https://www.google.com/webdesigner/

**А еще у него есть конвертер из Flash:**

- https://developers.google.com/swiffy/

**По поводу анимаций:**

- http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp
- http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

**Вектор (SVG):**

- http://frontender.info/using-svg/
- http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=28&id=1609

В целом это мало отличается от обычных html страничек, просто больше анимации. Ну и надо понимать, что мы не должны затронуть контент страницы своими стилями, анимациями или скриптами - следим за правильными селекторами, областью видимости переменных или просто все делаем во фрейме ;)